# How to return all record ids which are also part of the grouping in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a dataset that is laid out in a vertical format with a varying number of attributes per AppId. I currently group by the Attribute and Value to determine the maximum AppId. The scale attribute is being ignored in the Group By using "Where Attribute not in ('Scale')". I would also like to know which other AppId values are included in the grouping.

Below is an example of how the data is structured in the source table followed by how the data would look if it were flattened out. Next, is a query that'll give me the maximum AppId for each unique grouping and what the output looks like. How can I also return the other AppId values which are part of the grouping.

Source table:

```
+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
| PartId | AppId | Attribute |   Value    |
+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
| ABC    | ABC_1 | Color     | Red        |
| ABC    | ABC_1 | Shape     | Square     |
| ABC    | ABC_1 | Material  | Plastic    |
| ABC    | ABC_1 | Scale     | Celsius    |
| ABC    | ABC_2 | Color     | RED        |
| ABC    | ABC_2 | Shape     | Square     |
| ABC    | ABC_2 | Material  | Plastic    |
| ABC    | ABC_2 | Scale     | Fahrenheit |
| ABC    | ABC_3 | Color     | Red        |
| ABC    | ABC_4 | Color     | Red        |
| ABC    | ABC_5 | Color     | Green      |
| ABC    | ABC_5 | Shape     | Round      |
+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Pivoted representation:

```
+--------+-------+-------+--------+----------+------------+
| PartId | AppId | Color | Shape  | Material |   Scale    |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+----------+------------+
| ABC    | ABC_1 | Red   | Square | Plastic  | Celsius    |
| ABC    | ABC_2 | Red   | Square | Plastic  | Fahrenheit |
| ABC    | ABC_3 | Red   |        |          |            |
| ABC    | ABC_4 | Red   |        |          |            |
| ABC    | ABC_5 | Green | Round  |          |            |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+----------+------------+
```

My query to get the maximum AppId

```
Select Distinct Max(AppId) As GroupAppId
From VerticleData
Where Attribute not in ('Scale')
Group By Attribute, Value
```

Returns:

```
+------------+
| GroupAppId |
+------------+
| ABC_2      |
| ABC_4      |
| ABC_5      |
+------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------------+-------+
| GroupAppId | AppId |
+------------+-------+
| ABC_2      | ABC_1 |
| ABC_2      | ABC_2 |
| ABC_4      | ABC_3 |
| ABC_4      | ABC_4 |
| ABC_5      | ABC_5 |
+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using window functions:

```
select distinct GroupAppId, AppId
from (select vd.*, max(AppId) over (partition by Attribute, Value) as GroupAppId
      from VerticleData vd
      Where Attribute not in ('Scale')
     ) vd
Where Attribute not in ('Scale');
```

EDIT:

I think you may want something like this:

```
select max( GroupAppId), AppId
from (select vd.*, max(AppId) over (partition by Attribute, Value) as GroupAppId
      from VerticleData vd
      Where Attribute not in ('Scale')
     ) vd
where Attribute not in ('Scale')
group by AppId;
```

But I don't understand why `App_4` is not the right match for `App_1` and `App_2` (as this query gives).

EDIT II (by lmingle):
Working query:

```
Select distinct min(GroupAppID), AppId
From
(
    select distinct GroupAppId, AppId
    from (select vd.*, max(AppId) over (partition by Attribute, Value) as GroupAppId
        from VerticleData vd
        Where Attribute not in ('Scale')
        ) vd
    Where Attribute not in ('Scale')
) as a
Group By AppId
```

Comment: I'm getting back extra AppId values (ABC_1 & ABC_2) for GroupAppId ABC_4. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8a42/2

Comment: Why would you choose `ABC_2` for those two instead of `ABC_4`?

Comment: The pivoted representation for ABC_4 accidentally had shape and material filled in - I corrected it. ABC_3 & ABC_4 only have the attribute Color as red for the grouping. While ABC_1 & ABC_2 have Color, Shape and Material. The Attribute Scale is ignored.

Comment: I'm guessing one of the two queries in the answer will work then.

Comment: I was able to add some more surrounding logic to get the min(AppId) with the desired results. Not the prettiest query but the results are what I wanted.